# 0^2 or sqrt(0) Crashing App

Tags: android, eclipse, math

I'm trying to make an app to calculate the distance of a line segment, but when the distance should be 0, the app crashes. I'm assuming it has to do with attempting to square or square root 0, but I could be wrong. What is the problem, and how do I fix it?

My code:

```
package com.jenglanddev.quikformcalclite;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Distance extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

EditText x1, y1, x2, y2;
Button calc;
TextView dist1, dist2;
String X1, Y1, X2, Y2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.distance);
    x1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.distance_x1);
    y1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.distance_y1);
    x2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.distance_x2);
    y2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.distance_y2);
    calc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.distance_calc);
    dist1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.distance_distance1);
    dist2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.distance_distance2);
    calc.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

BigDecimal f;

X1 = x1.getText().toString();
if (X1.contentEquals("")) {
    X1 = "0";
}
Y1 = y1.getText().toString();
if (Y1.contentEquals("")) {
    Y1 = "0";
}
X2 = x2.getText().toString();
if (X2.contentEquals("")) {
    X2 = "0";
}
Y2 = y2.getText().toString();
if (Y2.contentEquals("")) {
    Y2 = "0";
}
BigDecimal x1 = new BigDecimal(X1);
BigDecimal y1 = new BigDecimal(Y1);
BigDecimal x2 = new BigDecimal(X2);
BigDecimal y2 = new BigDecimal(Y2);
BigDecimal a = x2.subtract(x1);
BigDecimal b = y2.subtract(y1);
BigDecimal c = a.multiply(a);
BigDecimal d = b.multiply(b);
BigDecimal e = c.add(d);
f = sqrt(e);
dist1.setText("Distance = The Square Root Of " + e + " Units");
        dist2.setText("Distance = " + f + " Units");
    }

    public static BigDecimal sqrt(BigDecimal value) {
        BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal(Math.sqrt(value.doubleValue()));
        return x.add(new BigDecimal(value.subtract(x.multiply(x)).doubleValue()
                / (x.doubleValue() * 2.0)));
    }

}
```

This works fine when the distance is any other number, just not 0.

Comment: Yeah.  What samgak posted.  That, and not knowing how to debug.  If you have some problem with complex expressions, split them up into simple ones with intermediate temp values, do a debug build and step through with your debugger.  You can then see what exectly is going on, narrow-down the problem and fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem isn't the sqrt, it's that you are dividing by zero.

When value is zero, then x will be zero, and you are dividing by x * 2.0.

Just add a check to return zero when value is zero.

```
if(value.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0)
    return BigDecimal.ZERO;
```

Comment: Should I put this in the sqrt method?